# LyX: Insert bullet list inside table cell

Tags: tables, lyx, enumerate

I want to add a bullet list inside a cell, but ..

[image: screenshot]

I can't.

Comment: Good question, but for the love of all things good and holy, please don't.

Comment: @SeanAllred, why not?

Comment: Lists should not be in tables; if it's a list, present it as a list. If you have that much information in a table, find another way to present it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set the width of the column to be able to do this. Right click the table cell, choose More --> Settings, and write a length in the *Width* box. This will make the column a paragraph column, where lists are allowed.